# SQL Server Backup Strategy for OLAP System

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need advise on what would be the best strategy for backups of OLAP database (WHICH is roughly 500gb in size)

Would this be fine:
1. Weekly (Full)
2. Daily (Differential)

No need to hourly log file back up as data doesn't changes during the day. It only changes when the ETL process is running.

Also current back of 500 gb is taking 9 hours .... I don't know whats going wrong.. is it could be done to ability to write to the RAID drives (means slow throughput). Which tool I can use to verify where the issue is ?

Regards

Comment: Is your server limited by CPU or IO when doing backups? Most likely IO in which case enabling backup compression may result in significantly less IO, though at a cost of higher CPU usage.

Comment: Are you talking about backing up OLAP cubes in SQL Server Analysis Services or backup in a datawarehouse database in SQL Server.

Comment: What's "the best" strategy? That's a subjective question which will garner subjective answers. What's best for me may not be best for you. How about taking the time to give is details on your recovery requirements, which ostensibly should be driven by the business needs.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you need, you know. FOr example, I am in a project where we have a possibly 21.000 gb olap database that does get rebuild but is not really backed up - we maintain the base data. Plus 2live servers with the data warehouse. If something fails we rebuild it from the enterprise schema.

> Also current back of 500 gb is taking 9 hours

Get more appropriate hardware. Maybe not a usb hard disc ;)

SQL Server can wonderfully handle RAID backup to multiple mediums at the same time.

But really, you need a LOT more data for an answer to even make sense.